# How to write regex which matches from a specificed string to the end of a line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I need a RegEx pattern which matches from "where" to the end of the line (`\n`).  For example, these would match:

```
"where x = 5\n"
"where x = 5 and y = 6\n"
"where (x = 5) and (y = 6) or (z = 7)\n"
```

So basically the pattern must start with "where" and end with a new-line character "\n".

**EDIT:**  RegEx pattern will be used in a Ruby (on Rails) project...

Comment: something like this? (where.*)\n

Comment: @Eineki Make that an answer. But, why parentheses? You also need `\b` before and after `where`. Otherwise, it will match strings like `"everywhere he goes.\n"`, `"wherever I meet him ...\n"`.

Comment: Is it possible that clauses span lines? If so, it's possible to miss portions using the dot metachar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your language, but the following is pretty universal:

```
/\b(WHERE .*)$/i
```

`$` is end of line. `i` is the flag for case insensitive.

Comment: No prob. Thanks to comments from **Eineki** and **sawa** too.

Answer (score 0):

[\bwhere\s(.*)$](http://rubular.com/r/gUv9slqVy8) The `()` group what the predicate so you can extract it.